# How to implement autocomplete search movie name in telegram bot

Tags: node.js, npm, autocomplete, telegram-bot

I am using NODEJS at backend to fetch movie data from IMDB NPM api.Following is my server.js code.

**server.js**

```js
var token ="token";
var telegramBot= require('node-telegram-bot-api');
var bot= new telegramBot(token,{polling:true});
var express= require('express');
var imdb = require('imdb-api');

var app =express();

app.listen(8080,function(){
  console.log("listening on 8080")
})

bot.onText(/Moviename/, function(msg, match) {
    data = msg.text;
    imdb.get(msg.text, function(err, movieList){
        console.log(movieList);
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id,movieList);
       //how i send data to bot when I type on keyboard 

    });
});
```

Comment: May be you need [Inline mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline)?

Answer (score 3):

For using `autocomplete` you might need to read [inline mode documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inline-mode)

Working example:

```
// Docs: https://github.com/telegraf/micro-bot
const { Composer } = require('micro-bot')
const imdb = require('imdb-api')

const bot = new Composer()

bot.on('inline_query', async (ctx) => {
  const movies = await imdb.get(ctx.inlineQuery.query)
  const results = movies.map((movie) => ({
    type: 'article',
    id: movie.id,
    title: movie.title,
    photo_url: movie.poster
  }))
  return ctx.answerInlineQuery(results)
})


module.exports = bot
```

[Another example of inline bot](https://gist.github.com/dotcypress/262ae2469c7b413407bc69c2f645c15e)